# Is it reasonable for an interface to specify that its implementations should be immutable?

Tags: java, design, object-oriented-design, immutability

Let's say I have an interface `A`. Instances of classes implementing this interface will be passed on to an algorithm that relies on these instances being immutable. For instance, it'll be invoking `A.execute(command)` in a recursive manner, a number of times that depends on the given parameters. If `execute()` changes the instance's state, the algorithm won't work as expected.

As immutability can't be enforced (at least in Java) by the interface, I'm thinking of just writing that in the class documentation, as a contract.

Is this reasonable or am I imposing an implementation detail?

Comment: In my experience anything the compiler won't enforce, won't be enforced, and even if its the caller's fault, you'll still have the hassle.

Comment: Rereading this question, I'm confused, and deleted my answer.  "It'll be invoking `A.execute(command)`" What is **it**?  Is it A or the algorithm?  Please provide more details or more skeleton code.  And why can't `A.execute()` simply decide, for correctness, not to change it's state?

Comment: Maybe the safest solution is for the algorithm to make a copy of A before starting.  (Or, better, for A to make a copy of itself, before calling the algorithm, I'm still confused who is calling whom here...).

Comment: I am sure the algorithm doesn't require that instances are immutable, but only that they don't change.

Comment: That would be called a specification, and it does demonstrate how base classes can enforce a contract more easily than an interface.

Comment: @gnasher729: Can you explain what you mean by an instance that does not change?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, this is definitely reasonable.

Just look at the [Streams API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects), for example, many constraints are expressed as JavaDocs instead of types. The [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface is another well-known example that specifies almost all of its constraints in the docs rather than in the types. Or, take `List.add`, which doesn't specify in its type that implementation actually need to add an element to the list, or `List.sort`, which doesn't specify in its type that implementations need to actually sort the list, and so on and so forth.

Java programmers *know* that types don't tell the whole story and that you need to consult the documentation for a full picture.

Comment: I read the long Comparator doc you cited, and see no mention of mutability. (And grep came up with nothing) The Streams docs discuss a mutable result, but I didn't see anything about mutable implementations. Please elaborate. Nor do your comments about List.add() and List.sort() seem relevant.  If you are arguing that one can't enforce immutability by types, only comments, I pretty much agree.  But specifying that an implementation of an Interface should be immutable is unreasonable.  It can't even count how many times it was called, or cache recent calculations?

Comment: @user949300 I think he means that Comparator also expresses constraints in its doc. These constraints don't necessarily relate to immutability. See the doc for [Comparator#compare](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-), it states that `The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y. (This implies that compare(x, y) must throw an exception if and only if compare(y, x) throws an exception.)`

Comment: That doc / comment basically says that `compare` must be transitive, if I recall my math terms correctly.  To my mind, that is a far cry from saying that the passed in x and y must be immutable.  In any case, OP (you) asked about immutability, not "general contracts".

Comment: Jorg, might be a long search, but this answer would be much better if you found a well known function with javadocs relating to immutability, the subject of the question.

Comment: So in other words we're back to using pre, post, peri conditions again?

Comment: @user949300  Your missing the point, it doesn't matter if it talks about immutability at all, its the fact that the documentation "enforces" rules and puts constraints on implementations that is important.   They could say "every implementation must output hello world" and it wouldn't matter, it would still serve prove the point of this answer, if the language can't enforce it, its appropriate to "enforce" a rule through documentation.

Comment: @snb: If the type system of the language you are using is too weak to express your constraints, then you need to find some other way to express your constraints. There's no way around that, except using a language with a better type system. All of the various properties mentioned here can be expressed in the type systems of Idris, Epigram, Guru, Coq, and Isabelle, for example. There are also languages like Spec♯ which integrate Contracts into the language and can even check a subset of them statically. But, if you need to express constraints, and you can't express them in the type system, …

Comment: … then you have to express it *somewhere*, and that pretty much leaves documentation (or the source code itself, but that is no solution for interfaces, which *don't have source code*).

Comment: @JörgWMittag  I was making a joke

Comment: @snb: I realized that, after you posted your second comment. However, it seems from the other comments that this point is actually somewhat controversial in the Java community, which surprises me somewhat, since Java's type system doesn't let you express very much, so documentation is pretty much the only way. I wonder how those who oppose to express constraints in documentation then express them?

Comment: To reiterate my "other comments", a **function** expressing some constraints, such as transitivity, is normal and fine.   Or even documenting that the returned List is immutable (or not), I do that a lot.  But OP specifically asked about an **interface** constraining implementations to be **immutable**.  Immutability is good, but that's a **big** constraint.  Some Collections variants do this as a subinterface, but, in my experience, I've never seen immutability required in a more general setting.  IMO, this answer should address this.

Comment: @user949300 Of course it is a big constraint, but how is it different from a constraint on a function?Regardless of whether it is rare or not, It depends on _why_ it should be immutable. If you access fields from a class with reflection and cache them, would be an example where you could state that implementations should be immutable as the internal state is accessed via reflection and cached. Or for fields used in equals and hashcode. OP's example is not a good one, as it states that `execute()` should behave consistently, which does not mean that the whole object should be immutable.

Comment: @NickL "If you access fields from a class with reflection and cache them" if you are doing that you deserve whatever evil fate awaits you when it mutates.  :-)

Comment: @user949300 In industry anything is possible.. all what matters is that it's a valid use case :) Whether it is a good decision to do such things depends on the context.. Of course there are more things you could do to enforce immutability if it is this important, like static or dynamic code anaysis. But that usually won't be an option if you have no control over the code.

Answer (score 4):

It is certainly reasonable for interfaces to specify that implementations don't do "a thing". This pattern can be seen in C, C++, and Fortran a lot. You will often see things called a [precondition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition)(before), [postcondition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondition)(after), and rarely pericondition (what happens while the function/class runs).  This has been further expanded upon in languages that actually implement language constructs in the form of [contracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).   Often you will see pre and post conditions on a C++ template function, which defines what can and can't be used inside of it, what properties the template must have (generics in java), etc, despite there being no way to enforce it (without very hard template meta programming that is).

In your case however, I'm not sure that the entire class need be immutable, or if only your function should be immutable instead of the entire class.

In your situation, instead of providing documentation defined constraints, you might be able to define a class that will contain the data you don't want to be accessed (assuming you even know what that is) that only implements accessors (which could all be final) and have that class implement the interface (or provide abstract method) for "execute". You couldn't guarantee immutability across the whole class, but you could enforce it on a subset of values you know about.  You could also use the final keyword in the same abstract class to achieve a similar effect (but it might be harder to accomplish)

In other languages (like C++) even without contracts you can force a function to be "const" which means that it doesn't modify the calling class. Java makes such things particularly difficult to accomplish.

Comment: A base class is more appropriate. Glad someone pointed out the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is `execute` not changing the state then requiring the instance to be inmutable is not reasonable. Even in the more complex cases, requiring that no method in the interface changes the state would be enough.

When you publicly document these requirements they are not implementation details anymore, they are promoted to public specifications or contracts.